# Poco installed with vcpkg is missing ssl related header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, poco-libraries, vcpkg

I use the command to install Poco.

```sh
vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows
```

And openssl x64 is installed. When i use visual studio 2022, it show me that it can't found the file `Poco/Net/SSLManager.h`, and Other libraries related to ssl. Why is this happening?

```cpp
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include "Poco/URI.h"
#include "Poco/Exception.h"
#include "Poco/SharedPtr.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SSLManager.h"
#include "Poco/Net/KeyConsoleHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ConsoleCertificateHandler.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, i get the answer.
when you install poco, just add this:

```sh
vcpkg install poco[netssl]
```

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider  accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using manifest mode than your vcpkg.json should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "poco",
      "features": ["netssl"]
    }
  ]
}
```